# Can you create some kind of execution file (e.g., exe) to run a python code on a computer that does not have python?

Tags: python

I am writing python code to automatically generate some report. Ultimately, I want other people at my firm to be able to run this easily by using some kind of execution file. None of them have python on their PC and I don't want them to install it (for operational difficult reason). Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following modules.

1. https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/
2. https://github.com/py2exe

With this you can generate an executable

Comment: But someone else who hasn't installed python on his PC can run the exe file?

Comment: Yes. See the description of Py2exe: Create standalone Windows programs from Python code